# How to get the count of each http status code efficiently?

Tags: java, algorithm, http-status-codes, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate to execute the URL and then I am printing out the http status code for it.

```
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
```

Now what I need to do is, I need to get the count of each status code and store it in map as key and value. Meaning, how many times each status code is coming. If http 200 status code is coming around 100 times, then I would like to see the count of it.

I can do it by having multiple temp variables for each status code and keep on increasing the count accordingly. But apart from this is there any other easy way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Map` maybe?
With the status as key, and value as counter.

```
Map<String,Integer> counters = new HashMap<>();
...
synchronized (counters) {

  String code = response.getStatusCode();
  Integer counter = counters.get(code);

  if (counter == null) {
    counters.put(code, 1);
  } else {
    counters.put(code, counter + 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I mentioned in my question. I can have several temp variables depending on how many Http Status codes are and then keep on incrementing the count accordingly. But is there any other easy way. That's what my question was.

Comment: with `Map` you will have only one "temp" variable. I don;t think will be simpler than that. I will try to update my answer with a small example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer,Integer> statusMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

public void store(int code)
{
    if (statusMap.containsKey(code))
    {
        int value = statusMap.get(code);
        statusMap.put(code,value+1);
    }
    else
    {
        statusMap.put(code,1);      
    }
}

public void list()
{
    Iterator<Integer> iter = statusMap.keySet().iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
        int code = iter.next();
        System.out.println(code + " : " + statusMap.get(code));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashMap`, then:

- if your httpcode wasn't already in the map, insert it with count = 1.
- if your httpcode already exist in the map, then increase its counter

  ```
  HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapCount = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

  // ...

  void updateMap(Integer httpCode) {
      if (!mapCount.containsKey(httpCode)) {
          mapCount.put(httpCode, 1);
      } else {
          // update counter
          int counter = mapCount.get(str).intValue() + 1;
          // overwrite existing with update counter
          mapCount.put(httpCode, counter + 1);
      }
  }

  // ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are actually asking for another way, you could go with an int array with the index of the int array representing the HTTP code received.

Something like :

```
// initialization
int[] responses = new int[600];

// for each received response
responses[response.getStatusCode().value()]++

// retrieving the number of HTTP 200 received
System.out.println("Number of HTTP 200 received : " + responses[HttpStatus.OK.value()] /* or simply responses[200] */);
```

Not sure what that would bring to the table though : even if it's a little faster, there's surely plenty of ints in that array that would end up wasted. Other answers detailed the `Map` approach which is better imho because more explicit about what you are trying to do (that is counting the number of occurrence of a particular HTTP status code). And clarity is key when writing code :)